# Lane-Riesenfeld subdivision algorithm, visual representation

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, algorithms

I want a VISUAL intuition based explanation of the Lane-Riesenfeld algorithm. By this I mean, run one iteration of the refining and smoothing operators on a small set of points (e.g 4-5 points).

The reason why I am asking this is because I am trying to understand a section of a paper that relies heavily on this algorithm and being able to visualize exactly how it works would help me understand the mathematical notation.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: If you are going to tag this with differential geometry, you'd better explain what's going on for us differential geometers.

Comment: (http://www.inf.usi.ch/hormann/papers/Cashman.2013.GLR.pdf). Maybe it's the paper you are reading...

Comment: @TedShifrin This is my bad, I am combining this algorithm with a multiresolution scheme on spheroids which involves computing geodesics, and tagged it due to that, but the question itself is not related to differential geometry. My bad, I was tired when I wrote the question.

Comment: You should make the question understandable to people with expertise in the tagged areas. What do you mean by spheroid? Geodesics on spheres are quite easy. On a general ellipsoid, totally difficult.